# Javascript get input and perform search function without sumbit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox, uri

I'm trying to get input from a textbox and use that value to perform a search without a submit button.So when the input in textbox changes, the page will display the corresponding search research result. After some search online below is what I have at the moment. It doesn't work. Nothing happens when I typed in the textbox. Can someone please help? Many thanks! I commented in the code as well.

```
<form name="form" method="post"/>   
         <input type="text" id="search" />  //when content in this text box changes, perform goSearch() and display result          
         <script type="text/javascript">                    
            var input = document.getElementById("search");
            function goSearch(){
                    var keyword = input.value; //get the input from textbox
                    //send keyword to search
                    var searchuri= somebaseuri +keyword; //send keyword with uri
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("GET", searchuri,true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        xhr.onload= function(){
                            var list = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            showResult(list);
                        }   
                        xhr.send(null);                         
                } 
                function showResult(list){
                     //format and display the result we get from the server
                    }

            input.onchange = goSearch(); //when input is changed, perform search function
            input.onblur =goSearch();
        }   
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: `input.onchange = goSearch();` assigns the result of **executing** the function, you want to assign a **reference** to the function: `input.onchange = goSearch;`.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work..

Comment: Define "didn't work". Attaching event listeners as properties has been working in browsers for nearly 20 years, strange that it should stop now.

Comment: @RobG Thanks mate for pointing it out. I think you are right. I will look in to this. I think there's something wrong with my code elsewhere.

Comment: @RobG Thank you! I tried your suggestion and it worked. However the odd thing is that it didn't work until I click the debugger console.. I mean the page doesn't get updated when I type in stuff in the textbox, until I click somewhere else on the page. Have you got any ideas why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to is attach an event listener to the input.

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("yourEvent", function() {
    // Your code to execute.
});
```

Or,

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("yourEvent", myFunctionHere);
```

**Edit 1**

Just to be on the safe side once you have done the above make sure you check the console for any errors as the request could be failing too.

**Edit 2**

yourEvent should contain the event you wish it to look for, for example in your case a `blur` event. When assigning an event using this method you do not need the *on* prefix.

**Reading Material**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a bit more about what should go into"yourEvent"?

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you a not so relevant question?  In the method body (// Your code to execute part), can I call a javascript function that is defined elsewhere in the html doc? I tried to do that but it's not working atm. Thanks in advance. I am quite new to this.

Comment: Use the second method where `myFunctionHere` is the function name, don't put the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my question is, in `myFunctionHere`, I can still call another function that's defined elsewhere in the html doc right?

Comment: @user3735871 why not give it a go and find out? It is a learning process. ;)

Comment: I did but it didn't work.. So I wonder if there's something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing.. :) But thanks! I guess I can call another function. The problem probably lies somewhere else...

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the issue, nor why it should work where the OP doesn't. Please don't recommend w3schools, a [*relevant specification*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener) and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) are far better references.